# Prevent SELECT N+1 issue in Entity Framework query using Joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to query something from an indirectly related entity into a single-purpose view model. Here's a repro of my entities:

```
public class Team {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Pet {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

Each class is in a `DbSet<T>` in my database context.

This is the view model I want to construct from a query:

```
public class PetViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TeamItIndirectlyBelongsTo { get; set; }
}
```

I do so with this query:

```
public PetViewModel[] QueryPetViewModel_1(string pattern) {
    using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString)) {
        return context.Pets
            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(pattern))
            .ToArray()
            .Select(p => new PetViewModel {
                Name = p.Name,
                TeamItIndirectlyBelongsTo = "TODO",
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

But obviously there's still a "TODO" in there.

Gotcha: **I can not change the entities at this moment**, so I can't just include a `List<Pet>` property or a `Team` property on `Member` to help out. I want to fix things inside the query at the moment.

Here's my current solution:

```
public PetViewModel[] QueryPetViewModel_2(string pattern) {
    using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString)) {
        var petInfos = context.Pets
            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(pattern))
            .Join(context.Members,
                p => p.Member.Id,
                m => m.Id,
                (p, m) => new { Pet = p, Member = m }
            )
            .ToArray();

        var result = new List<PetViewModel>();

        foreach (var info in petInfos) {
            var team = context.Teams
                .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Members.Any(m => m.Id == info.Member.Id));

            result.Add(new PetViewModel {
                Name = info.Pet.Name,
                TeamItIndirectlyBelongsTo = team?.Name,
            });
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

However, this has a "SELECT N+1" issue in there.

Is there a way to create just *one* EF query to get the desired result, without changing the entities?

PS. If you prefer a "plug and play" repro containing the above, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeroenheijmans/b44a120a0c0488646f84f530196d9fd0).

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why you cannot change these (quite strange) entities? I mean it will not require changes to database model if you fix them.

Comment: @Evk Good question. One reason is that (by now) I really want to learn more about how the queries work and what they can and cannot do. The original reason cannot really be made clear from the minimal repro, but boils down to the fact that I want to prevent others from querying this route unless they really know what they're doing (and not including the property on the record is a quick way to achieve that).

Comment: I realize that also means I might need to accept an answer "*Not possible. Go change your entities anyways you silly goose.*", if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: Maybe to achieve your goal you can add those properties but make them internal, then add a method to the data context to perform your query. Then other people cannot do it wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made the things quite harder by not providing the necessary navigation properties, which as @Evk mentioned in the comments do not affect your database structure, but allow EF to supply the necessary joins when you write something like `pet.Member.Team.Name` (what you need here).

The additional problem with your model is that you don't have a navigation path neither from `Team` to `Pet` nor from `Pet` to `Team` since the "joining" entity `Member` has no navigation properties.

Still it's possible to get the information needed with a single query in some not so intuitive way by using the existing navigation properties and unusual `join` operator like this:

```
var result = (
    from team in context.Teams
    from member in team.Members
    join pet in context.Pets on member.Id equals pet.Member.Id
    where pet.Name.Contains(pattern)
    select new PetViewModel
    {
        Name = pet.Name,
        TeamItIndirectlyBelongsTo = team.Name
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and proposed solution. I'm going to try and convert it to the method-based linq syntax and check if it works.

Comment: As usual with `Join` and `SelectMany`, the method syntax will be quite ugly. Some company policy requirement I guess.

Comment: I wonder in which sql it will be translated, compared to the "normal" way of doing this (if navigation properties were present).

Comment: @Evk Almost the same. Just the normal way generates `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` due to the fact that from the model it's unclear if the FK columns are required, so by convention EF considers them optional. So to make them exactly the same, the LINQ query should be written in some even uglier way.